# Cannot see Options Menu in Android

Tags: android, android-optionsmenu

I am trying to create a menu demo, but I am unable to see the menu. The only thing I can see is the "TextView" view in the layout. Below is the code:

menu.xml in (res\menu)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item 
    android:title="@string/new_game" 
    android:id="@+id/new_game">
    </item>
    <item 
    android:title="@string/quit" 
    android:id="@+id/quit"
    >
    </item>
    </group>
</menu>
```

demomenu.java

```
package com.test.demomenu;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class demomenu extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
    
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        //super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        MenuInflater inflater=getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.game_menu, menu);
        return true;
                
    }
    
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "This is the item", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return true;
        
    }
}
```

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/hello"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

strings.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="hello">Hello World, demomenu!</string>
    <string name="app_name">Demo Menu</string>
    <string name="new_game">New Game</string>
    <string name="quit">Quit</string>
</resources>
```

When I run the project, I can only see the "TextView" and not the menu. I would appreciate it if someone can tell me what is wrong with the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can have checkable items in an options menu.  The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Menu.html) states:

> Options menus: The icon menus do not support item check marks...

Try removing the `group` tag and see if the menu will display.

Comment: I did remove the group tag from menu but still the same issue, how can I debug the application.

Comment: @Sid so what exactly happens when you press the `menu` button? Does it display an empty menu?  Do you get an error in the logcat when you press the menu button?

Comment: now when I click on the menu button I can see the menus and click on the menu items and the toast is displayed. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are using `R.menu.game_menu` but you say your xml is named `menu.xml`.

Do you get anything in the logcat? Have you tried to debug? Is `onCreateOptionsMenu` called when you press the menu button?

Comparing you code to my [tutorial](http://www.droidnova.com/how-to-create-an-option-menu,427.html) I can't find a important difference.

Answer (score 1):

Sid... try [using LogCat](http://sites.google.com/site/jalcomputing/home/mac-osx-android-programming-tutorial/logcat).

So import

```
import android.util.*;
```

declare your TAG

```
private static final String TAG= "Sid";
```

Add debugging code to onOptionsItemSelected

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    Log.d(TAG,"onOptionsItemSelectedCalled");
    return true;

}
```

Run your app and press on the menu button. Now look into LogCat, after filtering for TAG:Sid and Log Level Debug, for the message tag:Sid Message:"onOptionsCalled".

JAL